# Linear Algebra. Math operations with picture

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have a picture in a Cartesian coordinate system:

We repeat the following operations $20$ times:

1. Increase image's size $\sqrt{2}$ times.
2. For each point of the image do the following: $A(x,y) \to A(x,x-y)$
3. Rotate the image by $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise.

Which coordinates will the point $(1,1)$ have after performing these operations?

Comment: Have you tried to see where the point (1,1) will land after applying the three operations once ? I think you'll discover the problem is not that hard at all, even if you repeat the operations 2017 times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write all these transformations as matrices:

\begin{align}T_1&=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2 & 0\\0&\sqrt 2\end{pmatrix}\\
T_2&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\\
T_3&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac 1{\sqrt2}&\frac 1{\sqrt2}\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

We want to then apply these transformations to the point $P=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$:

Apply first transformation (scale by $\sqrt2$):

\begin{align}P_1&=T_1 P\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2 & 0\\0&\sqrt 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2\\\sqrt2\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

Apply second transformation ($A(x,y)\to(A(x,x-y)$):

\begin{align}P_2&=T_2 P_1\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2\\\sqrt2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2\\0\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

Apply final transformation (rotation of $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise):

\begin{align}P_3&=T_3 P_2\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac 1{\sqrt2}&\frac 1{\sqrt2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

So now we can see that applying these transformations once doesn't change the point $P$, and so applying them $20$ times will also not change the point $P$

---

*Note: If you don't know about matrices yet, you can also do this using a graph - plot the point $(1,1)$ and then apply each transformation and see where your point ends up, athough scaling by $\sqrt 2$ by hand could be a bit tricky*

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The matrix representation for your three transformations are:

$$
T_1= \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2}&0\\
0&\sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix} \quad
T_2= \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix} \quad
T_3= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so your transformation is represented by the product:
$$
T=T_3T_2T_1
$$
Find this matrix and diagonalize it such that you have: $T=SDS^{-1}$

Thena $T^{20}=SD^{20}S^{-1}$ Where $D^{20}$ is a power of a diagonal matrix, i.e. a diagonal matrix that has as elements the powers of the elements of $D$.

This is the general method,.... but, in this case what is $T(1,1)^T$   ?  (Note that it is an eigenvector of $T$)